# Is it possible to bulk update specific values in postgresql efficiently?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a pipeline which is required to update a high number of rows in postgres where each row should be updated differently.

After looking up I found that this could be done using postgres UPDATE.. FROM.. syntax (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) and I came up with the following query that works perfectly fine:

```
  update grades 
  set course_id = data_table.course_id,
  student_id = data_table.student_id,
  grade = data_table.grade
  from 
    (select unnest(array[1,2]) as id, unnest(array['Math', 'Math']) as course_id, unnest(array[1000, 1001]) as student_id, unnest(array[95, 100]) as grade) as data_table
  where grades.id = data_table.id;
```

There's also another way to do it with `WITH` syntax like this:

```
update grades 
set course_id = data_table.course_id,
student_id = data_table.student_id,
grade = data_table.grade
from 
  (WITH vals (id, course_id, student_id, grade) as (VALUES (1, 'Math', 1000, 95), (2, 'Math', 1001, 100)) SELECT * from vals) as data_table
where grades.id = data_table.id;
```

My problem is that sometimes I want in some raws to update a field and sometime not. When I don't want to update I just want to keep the value that is currently in the table. In this case, I would want to potentially do something like:

```
  update grades g
  set course_id = data_table.course_id,
  student_id = data_table.student_id,
  grade = data_table.grade
  from 
    (select unnest(array[1,2]) as id, unnest(array[g.course_id, 'Math2']) as course_id, unnest(array[1000, 1001]) as student_id, unnest(array[95, g.grade]) as grade) as data_table
  where grades.id = data_table.id;
```

However this is not possible and I get back the error `HINT:  There is an entry for table "g", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

Also postgresql documentation specifies about it in the `From` description:

```
Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list,
unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list).
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to perform such bulk update ?
I've tried to use JOINs in inner query but with no luck..

Comment: Can the updated columns be null?

Comment: Yes they can be nullable

Answer (score 0):

Chose a value that cannot be a valid value, eg `'-1'` for course name and `-1` for a grade, and use that for your generated values, then use a `case` in the insert to direct whether to use the current value or not:

```
update grades g
set course_id = case when data_table.course_id = '-1' then course_id else data_table.course_id end,
student_id = data_table.student_id,
grade = case when data_table.grade = -1 then g.grade else data_table.grade end
from (
  select
    unnest(array[1,2]) as id,
    unnest(array['-1', 'Math2']) as course_id, -- use '-1' instead of g.course_id
    unnest(array[1000, 1001]) as student_id,
    unnest(array[95, -1]) as grade -- use -1 instead of g.grade
) as data_table
where grades.id = data_table.id
```

Pick whatever values you like for the impossible value.

---

If nulls were not allowed it would have been more straightforward and less code - use `null` for the impossible value and `coalesce()` in for the update value.